# Combobox in VB.NET Remembers Previous Selection

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms, combobox

I am working on a simple VB.Net windows form application in which I am filling out a form, and printing the results to a printer or saving a PDF.  The one part that I am having trouble with is how to clear the previous combobox selection when printing the form multiple times.

For example, on the form I have 6 different options a user can select:
Vacation, Medical, Company Business, Personal Business, Dental, and Other.  When I run my program, and select "Vacation" and preview the form, "Vacation" is selected.  However, when I close out of the preview window and make another selection, "Medical" and preview the form both selections now appear. If I repeat the process without closing the entire application, all items will be selected.  Is there a way to clear previous selections by either by event or modifying my logic?  Thanks

```
    Private Sub UltraTextEditor12_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UltraTextEditor12.SelectionChanged
    Dim Counter As Integer = 10
    For a As Integer = 0 To 6
        If Me.UltraTextEditor12.SelectedIndex = a Then
            C1Report1.Fields("Field" & Counter).Text = "XX"
        End If
        Counter += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

I was wondering, Should I call this method in my Print method?  I'm researching how that would look.  Here is my Print method:

```
    Private Sub Print(Optional ByVal PPreview As Boolean = False)
    ErrorProvider1.Clear()
    ErrorProvider2.Clear()

    If UltraTextEditor3.Text > UltraTextEditor6.Text Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(UltraTextEditor3, "From Date Must Be Earlier Than Through Date.")
        ErrorProvider2.SetError(UltraTextEditor6, "Through Date Must Be Later Than From Date.")
        Return
    End If

    Try
        Dim report As C1.Win.C1Report.C1Report = C1Report1

        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

        Dim pd As PrintDocument
        If My.Application.Info.AssemblyName.Contains("Laser") Then
            pd = C1Report1.Document
        Else
            pd = SetPrinter(OTF_Forms, C1Report1, Me)
        End If

        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
        PushFormValues(report)
        RequestInfo()

        If PPreview Then
            Dim preview As New Previewer
            preview.C1PrintPreview1.Document = pd
            preview.ShowDialog()
        Else
            pd.Print()
        End If

        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default

        Me.btnClose.Focus()

        ctrlkey = False
        Me.btnPrint.Text = "Print"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUzPc.png)

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place.  A CBO can only ever have at most one selected item.  The fact that the second time shows 2 segments means you have something somewhere else accumulating the selections

Comment: I added my Print method as well. Not sure whether I need to add logic there to make sure that the selections get updated.  Trying to do more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far after playing around with my code some more, I was able to find a solution.  What I ended up implementing was a line that cleared out the previous selection.  this may not get to the bottom of the underlying issue as to why the previous selection was saved, but I definitely fixed my issue.  I'll leave the incorrect code commented out just as a reference:

```
        Dim Counter As Integer = 10
    'For a As Integer = 0 To 6
    '    If Me.UltraTextEditor12.SelectedIndex = a Then
    '        C1Report1.Fields("Field" & Counter).Text = "XX"
    '    End If
    '    Counter += 1
    'Next
    For a As Integer = 0 To 5
        C1Report1.Fields("Field" & Counter).Text = ""
        If Me.UltraTextEditor12.SelectedIndex = a Then
            C1Report1.Fields("Field" & Counter).Text = "XX"
        End If
        Counter += 1
    Next
End Sub
```